# I need clear view for dynamically ask "do you want to update your app" when app is opening

Tags: java, android

I need clear view for dynamically ask "do you want to update your app" when android app is opening.

I am looking for yours help.....

Comment: @Please make your question clear! Do you need alert message or want to know  whether update is available ?

Comment: I want to show alert message.

Comment: Do you need coding for alert message or logical solution of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how alert dialog is created. For update alert, You could run a web service check for any newest version and if new version available in your server and fire the alert dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

            // Write your code here to invoke YES event
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding of your question, this is what you can do:

Create a web service which returns latest App Version. Call that web service every time app gets open and check whether latest version is equal to app version or not. If not, you can show pop-up for app updation.

In web service, you can set latest version hard-coded and Android side, you can check installed app version by following property:

```
int currentVerion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

Comment: I understand your answer but how can i check it's latest or not??